# What versions of Python and wxPython correspond to each version of OSX?

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, compatibility

I'd like to know what versions of Python and wxPython correspond to each version of OSX.  I'm interested to know exactly how far back some of my apps will remain compatible on a mac before having to install newer versions of Python and wxPython.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiger shipped with Python 2.3.5 and wxPython 2.5.3, Leopard ships with python 2.5.1 and wxPython 2.8.4.

wxPython was not shipped with previous versions.

---

OSX Lion has 2.7.1